# Why indexer of Dictionary is potential to return default value when the key is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

From what I understanding of Dictionary is that if you use indexer to access value from invalid key, a KeyNotFound exception is thrown, but if you look at the source code of Dictionary:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,184

```
public TValue this[TKey key] {
    get {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) 
           return entries[i].value;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
        return default(TValue);
    }
    ...
} 

internal static void ThrowKeyNotFoundException() {
   throw new System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException();
}
```

You can see that it is true that KeyNotFound exception will be thrown, but there is a statement after it `return default(TValue);`, it looks like this statement will never be executed, since an excetpion will always be thrown.

Even though the exception won't be thrown, the default of value will be returned, but isn't that KeyNotFound exception is always supposed to thrown, then why `return default(TValue);` is needed, really feel that this statement should be removed from the source code?

Comment: It must return something, because of code flow check. It cannot 'see' that the throw method never returns. So, yes it will never reach that code, until someone changes the implementation of that throw method not to throw anymore.

Comment: C# has no way of marking a method as "never returning", otherwise `ThrowKeyNotFoundException` could have been specified as such, removing the need for the return.

Answer (score 2):

During compilation (and before for that matter) [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) is performed. Static analysis can detect the conditions you're talking about (after all, *you* did!), but 1) that involves extending out of the box static analysis capabilities and 2) modifying the language itself, which in this case goes somewhat against the grain for the design of the language.

Semantically, we know that we'll never hit the `return default(TValue)` but syntactically it looks like we can. Part of language design is striking the right balance. Should the analyzer go into every possible method looking for a throw? Should it go into those methods' method calls? Where do you stop?

Like many things in programming, there are trade-offs in some form or another. In this case some of those trade-offs are in terms of complexity, readability, time (to analyze), etc.

So could what you're saying be done? Yes, it's possible, but is it worth it?

There are tools that extend the in-built static analysis by allowing you to annotate calls such as `ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFound` with an attribute that will hint that the code below it is heuristically unreachable, but you *still* can't remove that code because then you violate the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

When performing code analysis in order to compile a C# program, the Roslyn C# compiler doesn't "look ahead" into the body of a called method to determine whether it throws an exception or not; it simply relies on that method's signature. In this case, it sees that `ThrowKeyNotFoundException` returns `void` so cannot affect control flow in the calling indexer, thus the explicit `return` is required.

I'm not sure whether this is an oversight or intentional omission by the Roslyn team, but I'd expect the latter because analyzing **every logic branch** of **every called method and its called methods**, for the presence of a `throw` that would immediately cause termination, would be extremely expensive. Even if you simplify the above algorithm to only look for unconditional throws, it would still be expensive and would likely miss some cases. So, it's simpler to just not handle the possibility at all.

Of course, this issue can be avoided entirely if the code is changed to the following:

```cs
public TValue this[TKey key] {
    get {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) 
            return entries[i].value;
        throw ThrowHelper.ReturnKeyNotFoundException();
    }
    ...
}

internal static Exception ReturnKeyNotFoundException() {
    return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException();
}
```

but the BCL team presumably chose not to do this to avoid the performance penalty of pushing an entire exception onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the `return default(TValue);` will not been executed because an exception is thrown just before, however, the `return` statement is required here, because the `throw` statement is done inside an other scope, so the code will not compile if a there is not at least a `return` or an explicit `throw` statement in all the path of the scope.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, Yeah, you're right, I deleted the sample !

Answer (score -1):

It is needed for teh compiler but it will never be exectuted (as you stated). I would write the code the following:

```
public TValue this[TKey key] {
    get {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i < 0) 
           ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
        return entries[i].value;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is giving the same result, it is clear what the intention of the if is..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.